# comparing two string by adding pattern in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match two string and then append some tags in final output
For e.g.

```
$string1 = “Adaptive Actuator Failure and Structural <match>Damage</ match > Compensation of NASA”;

$string2 = “Adaptive Actuator Failure <?show $262#?>and Structural Damage <?show $262#?>Compensation of NASA”;
```

Output required :

```
“Adaptive Actuator Failure <?show $262#?>and Structural <match>Damage</match> <?show $262#?>Compensation of NASA”
```

Explanation : I want to map data from string1 to string2 but problem is with string2 which is having additional element. these element can come anywhere in string2.

Note : we cannot delete tag from string2 because we want it to be retain in final output

I tried adding an element pattern to each letter but it not working.

Code I tried :

```
$each = "(?:(?:\\s*<[\\#\\s\\\$\\w\\=\\-\\\"\\/\\?]+>\\s*)+)?".$each."(?:(?:\\s*<[\\#\\s\\$\\w\\=\\-\\\"\\/\\?]+>\\s*)+)?";
```

Variable $each contains each letter,symbol or space.

Any other logic ??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements. What are you matching? What are you adding? How does it relate to the match? I ask because it may be possible to formulate the problem in a simpler manner - and therefor solve it in a simpler way: generalized parsing instead of pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regexps in this way. Beware, it is not going to be too robust, it is only working for relativly sane inputs.

```
use strict;use warnings;
my $string1 = “Adaptive Actuator Failure and Structural <match>Damage</ match > Compensation of NASA”;

my $string2 = “Adaptive Actuator Failure <?show $262#?>and Structural Damage <?show $262#?>Compensation of NASA”;

#search string 1
my $se1 = $string1;
my $se2 = $string2;
#remove all tags
$se1 =~ s!<[^>]*>!!gis;
$se2 =~ s!<[^>]*>!!gis;
#normalize spaces
$se1 =~ s!\s+! !gis;
$se2 =~ s!\s+! !gis;
#found a match
if ($se1 eq $se2){
  #found each tag is s1
  my $s = $string1;
  while ( $s =~ s!(<[^>]*>)(.+?)(</\s*[^>]*>)!!is){
     my $begin_tag = $1;my $end_tag = $3;my $text = $2;
     ### replace the text in the s2 with tagged
     $string2 =~ s!$text!$begin_tag$text $end_tag!is;

  }
}
```